# Talking about something else other than the raspberry pi

Tags: discussion, support, on-off-topic, questions, asking-questions

So I recently posted a question about my raspberry pi: [Slanted Screen on raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137267/slanted-screen-on-raspbian),
But I was starting to think that I was asking about the tv instead of the raspberry pi.
I was talking about that the raspberry pi's interference is slanted(check the photo on there, and you will see what I am talking about). I asked for a solution, but I'm asking about solutions for the TV. Is that accepted, or is there another topic for this type of question?

Comment: I saw this question, but I tend to ignore questions with no detail or evidence (there are  so many these days) - especially if the OP fails to respond to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the problem happens when you plug more normal inputs into the tv (set-top boxes etc), then this question seems fair enough to me.  And although you unfortunately did not get much direct help with this, you have not gotten any close votes after almost 2 weeks, so the community seems to concur that it is not off-topic -- generally questions that are even a little bit questionable pick up a couple of close votes in their first few days.

Also, something you may or may not be aware of: These kinds of problems are common with the Pi.  That `hdmi_safe` does not work is a shame.

Comment: Thank you. I was unsure if this question is fair, but now I know!